# Poll choices are not multilanguage supported

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n, polls

Hi I have installed poll and [i18n_auto](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n_auto) with [gTranslate](https://www.drupal.org/project/gtranslate) modules,

Both are cool, But the translation occurs only for Poll title and Poll Body not for choices.

Is it possible to translate the choice please advice.

Thanks,

Edvin.